# Sum of an array and it's transpose

Tags: python, arrays

Consider a array `A` of shape (`n x 1`). The transpose of `A` will have the shape (`1 x n`). Why is that the sum of `A` and `A.T` (i.e `A + A.T`) give back an (`n x n`) array in Python?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Can you give us examples of what you are stuck on, and what you've attempted?

Comment: Wat did you expect?

Comment: Highlight relevant text.

Answer (score 0):

Your result will need n rows to comply to the structure of one of the arrays and n columns to comply to the structure of the other array.